# I want to run the process in background in my .net project

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, background

I have a piece of code which requires me to use a process, but i want that to run in background and not open console window.

```
public uint LaunchProcess(string sIPAddress, string sPort)
        {
            uint iPid = 0;
            try
            {
                logger.AddLog("LaunchProcess : " + sIPAddress + " " + sPort);
                object[] PlugInRunnerInfo = { StaticUtils.GetLocation(AgilentPluginCommonConstants.PlugInRunnerPath) + "\\" + "PlugInRunner.exe" + " " + sIPAddress + " " + sPort, null, null, 0 };

                //ManagementClass is a part of Windows Management Intrumentation,namespaces. One of its use is to provides access to manage applications.
                //Here this class is used to launch PlugInRunner as detached process.By setting the ManagementClass object's property 'CreateFlags' to value 0x00000008
                //we can start the PlugInRunner as detached one.
                using (var mgmtObject = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process"))
                {
                    var processStartupInfo = new ManagementClass("Win32_ProcessStartup");
                    processStartupInfo.Properties["CreateFlags"].Value = 0x00000008;//DETACHED_PROCESS.
                    var result = mgmtObject.InvokeMethod("Create", PlugInRunnerInfo);
                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        logger.AddLog("Process id " + Convert.ToUInt32(PlugInRunnerInfo[3]));
                        iPid = Convert.ToUInt32(PlugInRunnerInfo[3]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.AddLog("Exception " + ex.Message);
            }
            return iPid;
        }
```

Above is my code, can anyone help me run the process in background?

Comment: What is `PluginRunnerInfo`and why are you using `ManagementClass`? Is this question missing details? This does not look like the usual "I want to start X out-of-process".

Comment: @Fildor added full code

Comment: Ok. What exactly do you mean by "not on screen"? Does it open a GUI or a Console Window or something like that?

Comment: Are you aware of [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-6.0) ?

Comment: Unrelated and by the way: Most loggers support "structured logging", where it is better to provide a template string and arguments rather than interpolated or concatenated strings. And also, they provide better handling of Exceptions. Here for example, you are losing all the stacktrace info.

Comment: it opens a console window , which i want it to run in background

Comment: Using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start you can switch that off by setting parameters in the [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=net-6.0). I have no idea how that works with ManagementClass, though. But I guess, it should be possible.

Comment: @Fildor I was not able to do that, Can you be specific please and i should be able to do it with ManagementClass.

Comment: @Fildor I was able to Fix my issue, I just changed the output type as " windows application" and it worked, you gave me a suggestion to work on "Structured Logging", if you may, can you give example for the above code , how can i write the log without missing out the valuable info and again thanks for helping me out.